# Android-Kotlin preload a Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm using Kotlin. I don't know much about Java, Kotlin, and Android. I have two tables, Item and ItemOrderDetails.

The main files in my project are: ItemDatabase, ItemDao, ItemOrderDetailsDao, Item, ItemOrderDetails, ItemRepository, and ItemViewModel.

1. Entity (Item & ItemOrderDetails).
2. DAO (ItemDao & ItemOrderDetailsDao).
3. Database (ItemDatabase).
4. Repository (ItemRepository).
5. ViewModel (ItemViewModel).

First it is required to check if data exists or not. It should work like this:

If no data exists, preload all data in the two tables.

If data exists already in tables, update data, i.e., combine the data to be preloaded, and the data which already exists. If there are copies of the same data in this case, overwrite data.

Please tell me how to make changes to ItemDatabase.kt, to implement this.

**Log**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.itemapp, PID: 24878
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.itemapp/com.example.itemapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.itemapp.viewmodel.ItemViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.itemapp.viewmodel.ItemViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:275)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at com.example.itemapp.fragments.list.ListFragment.onCreateView(ListFragment.kt:43)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2699)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1199)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2637)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2589)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2723)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1200)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2637)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2589)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1335)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.example.itemapp.fragments.list.ListFragment.onCreateView(ListFragment.kt:43) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2699) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1199) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2637) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2589) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2723) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1200) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2637) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2589) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1335) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:267)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:323)
        at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
        at com.example.itemapp.data.ItemOrderDetailsDao_Impl.getAllItems(ItemOrderDetailsDao_Impl.java:109)
        at com.example.itemapp.repository.ItemRepository.<init>(ItemRepository.kt:15)
        at com.example.itemapp.viewmodel.ItemViewModel.<init>(ItemViewModel.kt:24)
            ... 38 more
```

ListFragment.kt

```
class ListFragment : Fragment(), RecyclerView_1_Adapter.OnItemClickListener1 {

    private lateinit var mItemViewModel: ItemViewModel
    private lateinit var nItemViewModel: ItemViewModel
    var itemList = mutableListOf<Item>()
    mItemViewModel.addItems(DataFragment.item_data)   // Error: Expecting member declaration.

    private lateinit var recyclerView1_adapter: RecyclerView_1_Adapter
    lateinit var recyclerView1 : RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)

        recyclerView1_adapter = RecyclerView_1_Adapter(itemList, this)
        recyclerView1 = view.recyclerview1
        recyclerView1.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        recyclerView1.adapter = recyclerView1_adapter

        // ItemViewModel
        mItemViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ItemViewModel::class.java)
        nItemViewModel.addItems(DataFragment.item_data)
        nItemViewModel.insertItems(DataFragment.item_order_details_data)

        mItemViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { item ->
            recyclerView1_adapter.setData(item)
        })
               
        return view
    }
          
}
```

RecyclerView_1_Adapter.kt

```
class RecyclerView_1_Adapter (
    var itemList: MutableList<Item>, // = mutableListOf<Item>()
    val listener1: OnItemClickListener1
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView_1_Adapter.RecyclerView_1_DataViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView_1_DataViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyview1_row, parent, false)
        return RecyclerView_1_DataViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView_1_DataViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = itemList[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            firstName_list.text = currentItem.firstName
            lastName_list.text = currentItem.lastName
        }
    }

    inner class RecyclerView_1_DataViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
        View.OnClickListener {

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val position = adapterPosition
            val currentItem2 = itemList[position]
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener1.onItemClick1(position, currentItem2)
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener1 {
        fun onItemClick1(position: Int, currentItem1: Item)
    }

    fun setData(item: MutableList<Item>){
        this.itemList = item
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

ItemDao.kt (updated)

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun addItem(item: Item)
//    suspend fun insertItems(item: Item)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun addItems(items: List<Item>)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateItem(item: Item)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteItem(item: Item)

    @Query("DELETE FROM item_table")
    suspend fun deleteAllItems()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun readAllData(): LiveData<MutableList<Item>>

}
```

ItemOrderDetailsDao.kt (updated)

```
@Dao
interface ItemOrderDetailsDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertItem(items: ItemOrderDetails)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertItems(item: List<ItemOrderDetails>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_order_details_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getAllItems(): MutableList<ItemOrderDetails>

}
```

ItemRepository.kt (updated)

```
class ItemRepository(
    private val itemDao: ItemDao,
    private val itemOrderDetailsDao: ItemOrderDetailsDao
) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<MutableList<Item>> = itemDao.readAllData()
    val getAllItems: MutableList<ItemOrderDetails> = itemOrderDetailsDao.getAllItems()
    /*suspend fun readAllData(user: Item){
        itemDao.readAllData(LiveData<List<Item>>)
    }*/

    suspend fun addItem(item: Item){
        itemDao.addItem(item)
    }

    suspend fun insertItem(item: ItemOrderDetails) {
        itemOrderDetailsDao.insertItem(item)
    }

    suspend fun addItems(items: List<Item>){
        itemDao.addItems(items)
    }

    suspend fun insertItems(items: List<ItemOrderDetails>){
        itemOrderDetailsDao.insertItems(items)
    }

    suspend fun updateItem(item: Item){
        itemDao.updateItem(item)
    }

    suspend fun deleteItem(item: Item){
        itemDao.deleteItem(item)
    }

    suspend fun deleteAllItems(){
        itemDao.deleteAllItems()
    }

}
```

ItemViewModel.kt (updated)

```
class ItemViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<MutableList<Item>>
    val getAllItems: MutableList<ItemOrderDetails>
    private val repository: ItemRepository

    init {
        val itemDao = App.db.itemDao()
        val itemOrderDetailsDao = App.db.itemOrderDetailsDao()
//        val itemDao = ItemDatabase.getDatabase(application).userDao()

        repository = ItemRepository(itemDao, itemOrderDetailsDao)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData
        getAllItems = repository.getAllItems
    }

    fun addItem(item: Item){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.addItem(item)
        }
    }

    fun insertItem(item: ItemOrderDetails) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.insertItem(item)
        }
    }

    fun addItems(items: List<Item>){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.addItems(items)
        }
    }

    fun insertItems(items: List<ItemOrderDetails>){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.insertItems(items)
        }
    }

    fun updateItem(item: Item){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.updateItem(item)
        }
    }

    fun deleteItem(item: Item){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.deleteItem(item)
        }
    }

    fun deleteAllItems(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.deleteAllItems()
        }
    }
    
    App.db.itemDao().addItemsFromFragment(DataFragment.item_data)   // Expecting member declaration
    App.db.itemOrderDetailsDao().insertItemsFromFragment(DataFragment.item_order_details_data)  // Expecting member declaration
   
}
```

DataFragment.kt (updated)

```
class DataFragment {

    companion object Data{
        var item_order : Int = 0
        var item_order_alert : Int = 0
        var selectedItems1 = arrayOf<Int>(0)

        var item_details_list = mutableListOf<ItemDetails>()
        
        val item_data = listOf(
            Item(0, "first_name_1", "last_name_1", "item_value_a_1"),
            Item(0, "first_name_2", "last_name_2", "item_value_a_2"),
            Item(0, "first_name_3", "last_name_3", "item_value_a_3")
        )

        val item_order_details_data = listOf(
            ItemOrderDetails(0, "item_group_1", "item_name_1", "item-value_b_1", "item_base_1", "item_up_1"),
            ItemOrderDetails(0, "item_group_2", "item_name_2", "item-value_b_2", "item_base_2", "item_up_2"),
            ItemOrderDetails(0, "item_group_3", "item_name_3", "item-value_b_3", "item_base_3", "item_up_3")
        )

        fun addItemsFromFragment(items: List<Item>){
            viewModel.addItems(items)
        }

        fun insertItemsFromFragment(items: List<ItemOrderDetails>){
            viewModel.insertItems(items)
        }

    }

}
```

MainActivity.kt (updated)

```
package com.example.itemapp

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import com.example.itemapp.data.App
import com.example.itemapp.fragments.add.DataFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setupActionBarWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.fragment))

        App.db.itemDao().addItemsFromFragment(DataFragment.item_data)
        App.db.itemOrderDetailsDao().insertItemsFromFragment(DataFragment.item_order_details_data)
        // Error - Unresolved reference: addItemsFromFragment
        // Error - Unresolved reference: insertItemsFromFragment        
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

ItemDatabase.kt (updated)

```
package com.example.itemapp.data

import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.example.itemapp.model.Item
import com.example.itemapp.model.ItemOrderDetails

@Database(
    entities = [
        Item::class,
        ItemOrderDetails::class
    ], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class ItemDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

//    abstract fun userDao(): ItemDao

    abstract fun getItemDao(): ItemDao
    abstract fun getItemDetailsDao(): ItemOrderDetailsDao

        /*companion object {
            @Volatile
            private var INSTANCE: ItemDatabase? = null

            fun getDatabase(context: Context): ItemDatabase {
                val tempInstance = INSTANCE
                if (tempInstance != null) {
                    return tempInstance
                }
                synchronized(this) {
                    val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        ItemDatabase::class.java,
                        "item_database"
                    ).build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                    return instance
                }
            }
        }*/
}
```

DbRepository.kt (updated)

```
package com.example.itemapp.data

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Room

    // Adding a new class to access DB.
class DbRepository (private val database: ItemDatabase) {

    companion object {
        private var instance: DbRepository? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): DbRepository {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: DbRepository(initializeDb(context)).also { instance = it }
            }
        }

        private fun initializeDb(context: Context): ItemDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                ItemDatabase::class.java, "ItemDb"
            ).build()
        }
    }

    fun itemDao():ItemDao = database. getItemDao()

    fun itemDetailsDao():ItemOrderDetailsDao = database.getItemDetailsDao()
}
```

App.kt (updated)

```
package com.example.itemapp.data

import android.app.Application

    //  Creating a single instance of the DbRepository throughout the app. It is done in App class.
class App : Application() {

    companion object {
        lateinit var db: DbRepository
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        db = DbRepository.getInstance(applicationContext)
    }
}

    /*You can access the App class from any class of that module like this:
    App.db.itemDao().insertItems(data)
    Note: Remember to call these DB functions on a background thread.*/
```

AndroidManifest.xml (updated)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.itemapp">

    <application
        android:name=".App"   // Error.

        /* Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.itemapp.App, was not 
           found in the project or the libraries. Unresolved class 'App' */ 

        android:allowBackup="true"   
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="com.example.itemapp.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Item.kt

```
package com.example.itemapp.model

import android.os.Parcelable
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "item_table")
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val item_value_a: String = "0"
    ): Parcelable
```

ItemOrderDetails.kt

```
package com.example.itemapp.model

import android.os.Parcelable
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "item_order_details_table")
data class ItemOrderDetails(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val item_group: String,
    val item_name: String,
    val item_value_b: String = "0",
    val item_base: String,
    val item_up: String
): Parcelable
```

The data for the tables are...

Item.kt data

```
val item_data = listOf(
            Item("first_name_1", "last_name_1", "item_value_a_1"),
            Item("first_name_2", "last_name_2", "item_value_a_2"),
            Item("first_name_3", "last_name_3", "item_value_a_3")
)
```

ItemOrderDetails.kt data

```
val item_order_details_data = listOf(
            ItemOrderDetails("item_group_1", "item_name_1", "item-value_b_1", "item_base_1", "item_up_1"),
            ItemOrderDetails("item_group_2", "item_name_2", "item-value_b_2", "item_base_2", "item_up_2"),
            ItemOrderDetails("item_group_3", "item_name_3", "item-value_b_3", "item_base_3", "item_up_3")
)
```

Comment: Are you asking for ROOM operations?

Comment: I just want somebody to give me the codes for my ItemDatabase.kt file, i.e., the codes according to my question. I read many things about this. I need the proper codes for implementing those features described in my question.

Comment: For preloading data, some extra codes are needed for ItemDatabase.kt file. I have two tables. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

1. Create another `Dao` like the `ItemDao` for the `ItemOrderDetails` table.
2. Add the following methods in both the `Dao`:

   ```
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
   suspend fun insertItems(item: List<YourModelName>)

   @Query("SELECT * FROM YourModelName")
   suspend fun getAllItems(): List<YourModelName>
   ```

These functions will help you in getting items from the `DB` and inserting items into it. `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE` will check whether there is an item already present in the table with the same primary key. If yes, it will replace it with the new item.

3. Change your `ItemDatabase` class to this:

   ```
   @Database(entities = [
       Item::class,
       ItemOrderDetails::class], version = 1)
   abstract class ItemDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

   abstract fun getItemDao(): ItemDao
   abstract fun getItemDetailsDao(): ItemOrderDetailsDao
   ```

   }
4. Add a new class to access `DB`.

   ```
   class DbRepository (private val database: ItemDatabase) {

   companion object {
       private var instance: DbRepository? = null

       fun getInstance(context: Context): DbRepository {
           return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
               instance ?: DbRepository(initializeDb(context)).also { instance = it }
           }
       }

       private fun initializeDb(context: Context): ItemDatabase {
           return Room.databaseBuilder(
               context,
               ItemDatabase::class.java, "ItemDb"
           ).build()
       }
   }

   fun itemDao():ItemDao = database. getItemDao()

   fun itemDetailsDao():ItemOrderDetailsDao = database.getItemDetailsDao()
   ```

   }
5. Create a single instance of the `DbRepository` throughout the app and you can do that in App class.

   ```
   class App: Application() {

   companion object {
       lateinit var db: DbRepository
   }

   override fun onCreate() {
       super.onCreate()
       db = DbRepository.getInstance(applicationContext)
   }
   ```

   }
6. You can access the `App` class from any class of that module like this:

   `App.db.itemDao().insertItems(data)`

Note: Remember to call these `DB` functions on a background thread.

---

**Edit 1.0**

Follow the steps to call the `DB` functions on a background thread.

1. Add `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"` dependency in your `app's gradle file`.
2. Add the `private val viewModel:ItemViewModel by viewModels()` in your `DataFragment`.
3. Add a new function in your `ItemRepository` class.

```
suspend fun addItems(items: List<Item>){
        itemDao.insertItems(item)
    }
```

4. Add a new function in your `ItemViewModel` class.

```
fun addItems(items: List<Item>){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.addItems(items)
        }
    }
```

3. Call the `DB` operation using the functions which are in your `ItemViewModel` class from your `DataFragment` class.

```
fun addItemsFromFragment(items: List<Item>){
        viewModel.addItems(items)
    }
```

---

**Edit 1.1**

Add this function in your `ItemDao` and do the same for `ItemDetailsDao`.

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertItems(item: List<Item>)
```

---

**Edit 1.2**

Add this function in your `ItemViewModel`.

```
fun addItems(items:List<Item>) {
   viewModelScope.launch {
       App.db.itemDao().insertItems(items)
   }
}
```

And call this function from your `Fragment`.

```
class DataFragment {

    companion object Data{
        var item_order : Int = 0
        var item_order_alert : Int = 0
        var selectedItems1 = arrayOf<Int>(0)

        var item_details_list = mutableListOf<ItemDetails>()
        
        val item_data = listOf(
            Item(0, "first_name_1", "last_name_1", "item_value_a_1"),
            Item(0, "first_name_2", "last_name_2", "item_value_a_2"),
            Item(0, "first_name_3", "last_name_3", "item_value_a_3")
        )

        val item_order_details_data = listOf(
            ItemOrderDetails(0, "item_group_1", "item_name_1", "item-value_b_1", "item_base_1", "item_up_1"),
            ItemOrderDetails(0, "item_group_2", "item_name_2", "item-value_b_2", "item_base_2", "item_up_2"),
            ItemOrderDetails(0, "item_group_3", "item_name_3", "item-value_b_3", "item_base_3", "item_up_3")
        )

        fun addItemsFromFragment(items: List<Item>){
            viewModel.addItems(items) // This will add your items. Remove lines which are causing error from your viewmodel.
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I think I'm making a mistake in the implementation of your answer. I have some doubts too.

Comment: I  have added ItemRepository, ItemOrderDetailsDao, and ItemDatabase after applying your answer. Please try to use the same variables which I have used, as I'm new to Kotlin, Room etc. I already have a working project to which I'm trying to include your codes, so that I can modify it.

Comment: There was a getDatabase() function which had usages in ItemViewModel and ItemDatabase. Now it's showing error. I want to include your codes in my project. I can understand your codes, only if they use the variable names in my project.

Comment: I will have to look into your code to help you out with this. If possible, share the code where you are facing the errors.

Comment: The main files in my project are: ItemDatabase, ItemDao, ItemOrderDetailsDao, Item, ItemOrderDetails, ItemRepository, and ItemViewModel.

Comment: 1. Entity (Item & ItemOrderDetails).
2. DAO (ItemDao & ItemOrderDetailsDao).
3. Database (ItemDatabase).
4. Repository (ItemRepository).
5. ViewModel (ItemViewModel).

Comment: Included the error in the end of my question.

Comment: The mistake is you have added all the classes in the `ItemDatabase` class. What you need to do now is separate the classes: `ItemDatabase` is a separate class, `DbRepository` is the separate class and App is a seperate class.

Comment: After separating these, add this line in the manifest application tag `android:name=".App"`, After that, replace the error line with this: `val itemDao = App.db.itemDao()`

Comment: Let me know if there is any other error you are facing.

Comment: All the updated files were added at the top of question. Now error is showing in AndroidManfest.xml (android:name=".App"). Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.itemapp.App, was not found in the project or the libraries. Unresolved class 'App'.

Comment: Also, in which file should I enter the data to be preloaded?

Comment: Please give the necessary codes for that too.

Comment: When you start typing `App` in the `android: name` field, you will get the suggestions then select from them. (Android search for the path of the file in your project and will provide the exact file name with the file path in the suggestions which needs to entered in that field)

Comment: Enter these codes in the `ViewModel` of the `View` ( Activity/Fragment ) in which you want to show the data or choose according to your logic.

Comment: There are errors in my project now. I need to include ViewBinding. I'll try this after fixing the errors.

Comment: I decided to use ViewBinding later. I entered the data in DataFragment.kt

Comment: I'm trying to call DB functions on a background thread in MainActivity.kt. This is to pre-load data in the tables, Item.kt and ItemOrderDetails.kt. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Now I'm getting error in MainActivity.kt.

Comment: `App.db.itemDao().insertItems(DataFragment.item_data)
        App.db.itemDao().insertItems(DataFragment.item_order_details_data)
        // How to to call these DB functions on a background thread?` The error is in insertItems() - "Unresolved reference: insertItems".

Comment: I added MainActivity and DataFragment at the top in my question. Please give me the codes to call these functions on a background thread.

Comment: @QwertyRty check out the Edit 1.0 in the answer.

Comment: I think I'm making a mistake in the implementation of your answer. After reading I realized to include some changes in my project. There are also some differences in the functions used by us in ItemDao and ItemOrderDetailsDao.

Comment: ItemDao  `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)  
    suspend fun addItem(item: Item)  @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun readAllData(): LiveData<MutableList<Item>>`

Comment: ItemOrderDetailsDao  ``` @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertItems(item: ItemOrderDetails)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_order_details_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getAllItems(): MutableList<ItemOrderDetails> ```

Comment: ItemDao `suspend fun addItem(item: Item)` `fun readAllData(): LiveData<MutableList<Item>>`

Comment: ItemOrderDetailsDao  `suspend fun insertItems(item: ItemOrderDetails)`  `fun getAllItems(): MutableList<ItemOrderDetails>`

Comment: Some important sections in my project are added at the top of my question. Please use the same variables and functions. I know only some basic stuff. You can understand the functions I'm using in my ItemDao and ItemOrderDetailsDao from there.

Comment: Added `private val viewModel` in DataFragment. See section 5, at the top. I don't know how to use the `addItemsFromFragment()`. I'm already using `addItem()` in my project. See sections 1, 3, and 4.

Comment: The latest error is given at the bottom of my question. It's in MainActivity. I don't know what to do there. Please give codes, as I cannot understand your hints to solve this.

Comment: Updated ItemViewModel. It is added after all sections.

Comment: You can only call a `suspend function` from a `coroutine scope` and that `ViewModel scope` will provide you. So, check out the code of view model. And in your `DAOs` you implement the function to add a list of items as I have done in `Edit 1.0`.

Comment: Showing error in ItemRepository. Unresolved reference: addItems. All errors are added to bottom of question. Added ItemRepository, ItemViewModel, and DataFragment below important sections.

Comment: check `Edit 1.1 `

Comment: Updated ItemDao, ItemOrderDetailsDao, ItemRepository, ItemViewModel, DataFragment and added these at the top of my question. Now error is only in MainActivity.

Comment: You have to call insert functions from the fragment's view model, not from the main activity.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Now the error is in ItemViewModel. Updated ItemViewModel and is added above.

Comment: The error is `Expecting member declaration`. It is added at the bottom of my question.

Comment: How to call insert functions from the ItemViewModel?

Comment: I don't know how to do this. Please give me the codes.

Comment: The function definitions of `addItemsFromFragment()` and  `insertItemsFromFragment()` are in DataFragment. How to call these in ItemViewModel? This is what you wanted me to do, right?

Comment: The project is nearly complete. Please give me the remaining codes. I don't need you to explain how those work.

Comment: I'll figure it out myself, just give me the codes.

Comment: Now the error is in ItemViewModel. Updated ItemViewModel and is added above. The error is `Expecting member declaration`. It is added at the bottom of my question.

Comment: In ItemViewModel, I'm trying to call the functions, `addItemsFromFragment()` and `insertItemsFromFragment()` to insert data from the lists given in DataFragment. The function definitions of `addItemsFromFragment()` and `insertItemsFromFragment()` are in DataFragment.

Comment: I just need the codes to properly call these functions to insert data into the database. I think, with this my project will be complete.

Comment: `addItemsFromFragment()` inserts data into Item table. `insertItemsFromFragment()` inserts data into ItemOrderDetails table.

Comment: Please give me the remaining codes. I don't need you to explain how those work. I'll figure it out myself, just give me the codes.

Comment: Okay. Create two functions in your `ItemViewModel` one accepts the list of `Item` and the other accept the list of `itemOrderDetails`. Now call those functions of the ViewModel to insert data into the db.

Comment: I had created the functions to accept the lists of `Item` and `ItemOrderDetails`. They are `addItems(items: List<Item>)` and `insertItems(items: List<ItemOrderDetails>)`. They can be found in `ItemDao`, `ItemOrderDetailsDao`, `ItemRepository`, and `ItemViewModel`.

Comment: I tried to call those functions of the ViewModel to insert data into the db using the codes, `App.db.itemDao().addItemsFromFragment(DataFragment.item_data)   // Error: Expecting member declaration` and `App.db.itemOrderDetailsDao().insertItemsFromFragment(DataFragment.item_order_details_data)  // Error: Expecting member declaration` in `ItemViewModel`.

Comment: Then it is showing error in `ItemViewModel`. It is added at the top of my question. Please give the codes to call these functions properly so that, I can insert data into the db.

Comment: Take a look at `ItemViewModel` and `DataFragment`, which are given in my question.

Comment: Don't pass data as `DataFragment.item_data`, check Edit 1.2

Comment: I realised some more things to inform you. I have a `ListFragment` that has a `RecyclerView` which displays data from the `Item` table. The pre-loaded data has to be displayed here. `RecyclerView_1_Adapter` is the adapter for this `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @QwertyRty This is going out, I will need to see your code for any further changes.

Comment: All codes are added above. Now error is in `ListFragment`. The error is `Expecting member declaration`.

Comment: In ListFragment, I'm calling `addItems()` to insert data into `Item` table from the list `item_data` given in `DataFragment`.

Comment: I removed all the errors in the code. Now when I run, the app keeps crashing.

Comment: The log is added above.

Comment: The problems started with this - `Cannot create an instance of class com.example.itemapp.viewmodel.ItemViewModel`

Comment: Updated ListFragment

Comment: In ListFragment, `LiveData` is used to monitor changes in the RecyclerView.

Comment: In ListFragment I made these changes:

Comment: `private lateinit var nItemViewModel: ItemViewModel`

Comment: `nItemViewModel.addItems(DataFragment.item_data)`

Comment: `nItemViewModel.insertItems(DataFragment.item_order_details_data)`

Comment: For test, try adding items directly form listfragment instead from data fragment

Comment: and write viewmodel code apart from initialization in `onStart()` method

Comment: The problem is with ViewModelProvider method in ListFragment. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I think the problem is setting data in adapter in `onCreateView()`

Comment: "Setting data in adapter in onCreateView()" - It was working fine in the old version of app. I looked up the error, and saw that it is related to...

Comment: `ViewModelProvider(this).get(ItemViewModel::class.java)`

Comment: The related stuff I found on Google says that it is necessary to create ViewModelFactory. I don't know how to implement that in my project.

Comment: I would like to try a different approach. My old project was working fine with only `ItemDatabase`.

Comment: Can you include the functions of `DbRepository` and `App`, that you told me to create into `ItemDatabase`. Then I could try again after removing those two from my project and test again. Those were the only major changes that you suggested. I think somehow it is in conflict with my project.

Comment: In the `ItemDatabase`, first it is required to check if data exists or not. It should work like this:

If no data exists, preload all data in the two tables.

If data exists already in tables, update data, i.e., combine the data to be preloaded, and the data which already exists. If there are copies of the same data in this case, overwrite data.

Comment: These are the things I need in `ItemDatabase`. Can't you include that using `if.. else..` blocks or something similar to it in `ItemDatabase` itself? Then I think my app would work.

Comment: My app was working without any problems that way. I don't know much about Android, and Kotlin.

Comment: There is no problem with `DbRepository` and `App`. I checked that. Now going to try `onStart()` method.